# NIFI: how can i replace ',' with new line in replace txt

Tags: json, regex, apache-nifi

I  want to  parse  json response in nifi   processor I  have json data  like this :

```
{
  "squadName": "Super hero squad",
  "homeTown": "Metro City",
  "formed": 2016,
  "secretBase": "Super tower",
  "active": true,
  "Data":{"row": [
    {
      "name": "Molecule Man",
      "age": 29,
      "secretIdentity": "Dan Jukes",
      "powers": [
        "Radiation resistance",
        "Turning tiny",
        "Radiation blast"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Madame Uppercut",
      "age": 39,
      "secretIdentity": "Jane Wilson",
      "powers": [
        "Million tonne punch",
        "Damage resistance",
        "Superhuman reflexes"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Eternal Flame",
      "age": 1000000,
      "secretIdentity": "Unknown",
      "powers": [
        "Immortality",
        "Heat Immunity",
        "Inferno",
        "Teleportation",
        "Interdimensional travel"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

and i  want totransform it  into this  format:

```
  {"name": "Molecule Man", "age": 29,  "secretIdentity": "Dan Jukes", "powers":  ["Radiation resistance", "Turning tiny", "Radiation blast"]}
   {name": "Molecule Man", "age": 29,  "secretIdentity": "Dan Jukes", "powers":  ["Radiation resistance", "Turning tiny", "Radiation blast"]}
   {"name": "Molecule Man", "age": 29,  "secretIdentity": "Dan Jukes", "powers":  ["Radiation resistance", "Turning tiny", "Radiation blast"]}
```

I  have  already  used  this expression inside  evaluatejsonpath  processor :
**$.Data['row']** and   thanks  to it  i got  row  data  then  i  have used  another  expression inside replacetext  processor: **[]**  to get  rid  of   this  '[]'    **but   i  can't  replace  ','   with   new  line   how  can  i do  this?**

Comment: What are you replacing the coma with? **\n**? Also - shouldn't you (and wouldn't it be easier to) parse the JSON using any existing framework for this? Also I don't understand how do you want to get rid of newlines by replacing commas with them (unless there is problem with your formatting in question).

Comment: I want  to replace  commans  after  { }  with   new  line

Comment: Then simply capture `},` and replace it with `}\n`. This will replace all commas that are next to `}` with a newline. This isn't what you provided with   "_and i want totransform it into this format_", as this will add newlines where you already have them...

Comment: how  can  i  do it   in regex   can you  reccomend me any  online regex  simuator  i have  found   one  but it is useless  for me

Comment: Please check my answer, if you have further questions about my solution post them as a comment there. As for regex simulator I recommend regex101.com (linked demos in my answer).

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution

If you simply want to have each row in single line, you can simply delete all newlines that are not prefixed with `},`. Say after your work described in your last paragraph you ended up with something like this:

```
{
  "name": "Molecule Man",
  "age": 29,
  "secretIdentity": "Dan Jukes",
  "powers": [
    "Radiation resistance",
    "Turning tiny",
    "Radiation blast"
  ]
},
{
  "name": "Madame Uppercut",
  "age": 39,
  "secretIdentity": "Jane Wilson",
  "powers": [
    "Million tonne punch",
    "Damage resistance",
    "Superhuman reflexes"
  ]
},
{
  "name": "Eternal Flame",
  "age": 1000000,
  "secretIdentity": "Unknown",
  "powers": [
    "Immortality",
    "Heat Immunity",
    "Inferno",
    "Teleportation",
    "Interdimensional travel"
  ]
}
```

Now, substitute `(?<!},)\n` with  (leave this empty, it's not a space). You can see this change here: [Link to Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/TakfWw/2)

You can also get rid of multiple spaces by changing all occurences of multiple spaces to single space with this replacement: substitute `(?<!},)\s+` with `_` (single space, not an underscore of course) (demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/TakfWw/3/)

---

#### How does it work?

I have divided the work into two phases (you could do this with one regex, but for simplicity sake I made the division). First of all, I look for all newlines that are there in the text that are not preceded with `},`, as these are not the newlines we want to remove.

After removing this we almost get what we want - but it's ugly because of multiple spaces and broken formatting. So again I search for all whitespace characters (excluding the `},` lines again, as newline is also a whitespace character), and then change all multiple occurences with a single occurence of a space.

End result:

```
{ "name": "Molecule Man", "age": 29, "secretIdentity": "Dan Jukes", "powers": [ "Radiation resistance", "Turning tiny", "Radiation blast" ]},
{ "name": "Madame Uppercut", "age": 39, "secretIdentity": "Jane Wilson", "powers": [ "Million tonne punch", "Damage resistance", "Superhuman reflexes" ]},
{ "name": "Eternal Flame", "age": 1000000, "secretIdentity": "Unknown", "powers": [ "Immortality", "Heat Immunity", "Inferno", "Teleportation", "Interdimensional travel" ]}
```

Comment: ok, i   have  used  this in my search value  : (?s:((?<!},)\n))  and  this expression ${$1:replace('},', '\n')} in replacement  value   but  it  doesn't  cahnge anything

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't help you with the usage of Nifi since I have never used it before. My solution simply covers regexes - maybe someone will be able to help you more with this.

Comment: Also, don't replace `},` with `\n`, this won't give you the expected result. Please read through my solution again.